# Using javascript(ajax, jquery?) to delete an object(user etc) from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm pretty new to C# MVC3, javascript, jquery, ajax and such. Right now i've got the usual index with edit and delete scaffolding, but i would like to use a popover from bootstrap to delete rows from the database.

The popover is working, and looks fine.

Could anyone point me in the right direction. I don't know what to google atm.

Comment: You should provide more info on what you want to do, and add an ASP.NET tag. Since, when it comes down to Database operations, the server is where it _all goes down, innit_

Comment: With *MVC3*, do you mean Spring MVC?

Answer (score 0):

considered view: use jquery to remove/hide column or row

on server: use id from view to delete that elements from db.

Sorry if i didn't understand your question.